# GIF individual frame timing

Tags: video, premiere

I have a GIF that uses variable framerates throughout. It plays back correctly in web browsers, and opening it in GIMP shows the time for each frame. If I import it into Premiere CS6, it plays at a constant average framerate.

Is there a way to preserve the correct frame timing without cutting and splicing several copies of the source GIF?

Answer (score 1):

That does sound like a tricky issue. Have you tried opening the GIF in PhotoShop using video to layers (file > import > video to layers)? If so, did the timing appear accurate? What are you ultimately trying to do with the GIF?

http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-video-animation-layers-photoshop.html

Comment: I have a GIF that is something like: Frame 1 - 1000 ms, Frames 2-9 - 50 ms each, Frame 10 - 3000 ms. If I import this to Premiere, it plays at the average overall framerate - 400 ms per frame. I eventually "solved" the problem by inserting each piece of the GIF separately, then adjusting the framerates individually.